# Incorrect datetime value on TIMESTAMP column

Tags: php, mysql, phpactiverecord

I have a mysql (version 5.6.24) with a table where one of the columns `updated_at` is a `TIMESTAMP` `default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

I never needed to worry about this column as it updates itself like expected when directly editing the database.

I recently moved my app to a new server and a error starting happening on my php script:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ActiveRecord\DatabaseException' with message '22007, 1292, 
Incorrect datetime value: '2015-06-10 22:15:03 UTC' for column 'updated_at' at row 1'
```

I'm using PHP ActiveRecord, and this is where the error takes place:

```
$user->name = $userData->name;
$user->avatar = $userData->avatar;
$user->save();
```

Just to make sure, I tried to add in the script (before save()):

```
$user->updated_at = "2015-06-10 22:15:03";
```

and then:

```
$user->updated_at = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

The error persisted. How can I solve this?

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez The language and timezone are the same. They weren't when I installed mysql. Could that be it?

Comment: Exported as .sql, and then changed the timezone via `dpkg-reconfigure tzdata`

Comment: In my personal experience, language has always been the problem. Are you sure the operating system has the same language?

Comment: Not sure this has anything to do with your problem, but: The `updated_at` column (specifically by name) is updated automatically by phpactiverecord so now it is updated by phpactiverecord and by the database. To stop confusion who is 'responsible' I would give it another name so phpactiverecord doesn't try to mess with it?